# How many block.one employees are on stack exchange answering questions for the community?

Tags: discussion

Seeing that most of the answers are from one user Confused00, how many other block.one employees are answering questions from the community?

Comment: Its good for everyone to know as I'm sure some are curious to how supportive block.one is supportive of the developers that post here. Thanks for the dedication btw.

Comment: I can't tell who of our community is a member of block.one, but Dan (@Bytemaster). Other participants may be part of the blockproducers or also active in the developer Telegram or GitHub. Also some people (like myself) are just enthusiasts doing this in there spare time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the current time, confused00 does not work for block.one.

Current B1 employees on the site include:

- sergej-metelin
- todd-fleming
- bytemaster
- bart-wyatt

Feel free to update this with other members who I have missed