# How can Block.one support EOSIO Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to check in with how you think we can support this site?
Do we need some design work?
Any meta-related activities to help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great idea. Thanks for participating!

**Simple Solutions:**

I think design is not the most important thing for most developers, but an **active community** is. So if you guys would **use tags** on your answers and **link to your official documentation** people would feel the "official" support. This is also linked to some confusion who is a actual member of Block.one (see [this question](https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/how-many-block-one-employees-are-on-stack-exchange-answering-questions-for-the-c))

This would work backwards as well, if you **link discussions and further solutions from your developer portal or from GitHub back to StackExchange**, so that both sites could profit. Also doing a **Medium/Steemit post** about this community would boost the popularity and infrastructure.

After that a new design would be fine as well.

**Personal Opinion:**

Most of the time I am coding something and face a problem **I would prefer a qualified StackExchange solution** from a search engine before anything else. If an answer is good, it is straight up and has just enough explained. Documentations are fine but most of the time hard to read and I use it mostly when I more or less know exactly what I want to do or what method I am searching for e.g. additional method parameters.

TL:DR First step: just let people know that you guys are here.